# Зачем нужен Object.prototype?

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять, зачем в данной функции использовать `Object.prototype` для того, чтобы проверить `input` и определить `String` ли это? 
В чем разница использования `Object.prototype.toString.call(input)` и использования `toString.call(input)`?

```
var isString = function (input) {
    // Почему здесь используют Object.prototype,
    // когда можно просто использовать метод toString.call(input) ?
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(input) === '[object String]') { 
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

console.log(isString('w3resource'));
console.log(isString([0, 1, 2, 4]));
console.log(isString({name: "Nureke", age: 24}));
```

Comment: тут лучше `typeof` использовать

Comment: `if(typeof input == 'string') return true?true:false; else return false?true:false;`

Answer (score 2):

Обычно, потомки переопределяют `toString` от объекта.
Это, в сущности, **разные** методы.

Например, `Array.prototype.toString` собирает элементы массива через запятую.
А `Object.prototype.toString` с помощью внутренних колдунств, определяет тип и выводит его в определённом формате.

Т. е. если нужно определить тип - берём метод прототипа объекта и, обязательно, устанавливаем `this`, без него объект не будет ожидаемо работать.

`toString.call(input) === Object.prototype.toString`, так что вызовы *обычно* эквивалентны (спасибо @Grundy за правку).
Однако, если кто-то сделает `var toString = 42;` в глобальной области, но будет плохо.

P. S. Зачем `if`? Сравнение уже возвращает булево значение.

Comment: в глобальной области методы берутся из объекта window, поэтому вызов `toString.call(input)` эквивалентен `window.toString.call(input)`. В свою очередь `Object.prototype.toString === window.toString`.

Comment: Не знал, спасибо за информацию.